# Git remote repository for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, git, visual-studio-2015

I'm learning how to use Git source control with Visual Studio 2015. Our situation is simple - there are two developers in different states, working on the same ASP.NET project, there is a file server that we both can use (and used in the past with Mercurial). We just need to setup a remote repository and be able to work on the same project. Git has Network protocol, so we should be able to do this.

But I cannot figure out how. Every time I want to setup a remote connection in VS I'm getting prompted to connect to TFS which we don't have. The instructions from Microsoft say:

"You can use Visual Studio and Git to collaborate on TFS (on-premises or in the cloud), on CodePlex, or on a third-party service such as GitHub or Bitbucket."

How about just our company's network?

Thank you.